# Reword top % tooltip on developer story

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story

I've got a minor feature request. In the new developer story, a section shows when a user is in the top x% of a tag, and this section has a tooltip when you hover over it. The tooltip reads:

> This user is part of the top x% Stack Overflow answerers on those technologies

I think this should be reworded, it just doesn't sound right, especially if the user is only in the top x% for *one* tag.

#### I think it should be changed to:

For when a user is only in top x% for *one* tag:

> This user is part of the top x% Stack Overflow answerers for this technology
>
> *or*
>
> This user is part of the top x% Stack Overflow answerers in this technology

For multiple tags:

> This user is part of the top x% Stack Overflow answerers for these technologies

Using "these" (plural of "this") sounds better than "those". It's weird referring to "those technologies", when the technologies are listed right next to the tooltip

Comment: Any of the prepositions work equally well: on, for, or in. Choosing between them is simply a matter of style, not grammar, and there won't even be a universal stylistic preference to be found. But you're totally right about "those" vs. "these". In a tooltip, you definitely want to show proximity!

Comment: I know it wasn't you, but who decided that every minor constituent part of what used to be called IT is now a full-blown (and simultaneously meaningless) "technology"? Now, if it said "tag", I'd have no complaint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your report <3

These issues have now been fixed and should be up with our next prod build, on `rev 2016.12.6.4293`.

Comment: I know I must be really out of touch, but until now I had thought that <3 referred to a certain part of the male human anatomy. Thanks for the... er... heads up... on that.